# Unable to extract session id from cookie data in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsessionid

I need to get JSESSIONID from cookie data in jmeter but I am failing in doing so.

**Process I am following** -
In my .jmx file I have added regular expression extractor as:
- Reference Name - session_id
- Regular Expression - Cookie Data\s*:\s*CMS_JSESSIONID=([^;]*)
- Template - $1$
- Match - 0
- Default Value - Not found

This I have added under my second url request.
I am trying to extract JSESSION id from "Request" page which comes under View Results tree:

**Cookie Data:
CMS_JSESSIONID=8456329D51C6D7F3B924325A336CA31**E

And for checking I have added debug sampler but every time result is showing "Not found".

Kindly please help.

Thanks,
Nitish

Comment: Can you share why you need to extract this? If you use JMeter's cookie manager then JMeter will itself manage the cookies / session Id etc

Answer (score 10):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie) cookies are coming with `Set-Cookie` header so you need to amend your Regular Expression Extractor like:

- Field to check: `Response Headers`
- Regular Expression: `Set-Cookie\s*:\sCMS_JSESSIONID=([^;])`

---

However there is an easier way to get the cookie value (steps 1 and 2 required only once)

1. Add `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` line to *user.properties* file
2. Restart JMeter
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to your Test Plan
4. Access your cookie value as `${COOKIE_CMS_JSESSIONID}` where required.

Comment: Thanks, It worked like a charm. But I used ${COOKIE_JSESSIONID} to access